# how i get total of item in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get the overall number of items in each iteration.my code is this

```
    <ul class="phones">
       <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp"  
        ng-init="index()"     class="thumbnail">
         <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb">
           <img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}">
         </a>
          <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">{{phone.name}}</a>
         <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
       </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
   {{ total }}
</div>
```

Controller

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope, $http)
{
$scope.total =0;
$scope.index =function()
{
    $scope.total ++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By dynamic you mean total no of phones currently displayed after filter is applied.

```
<ul class="phones">
   <li ng-repeat="phone in filtered = (phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp)"  
    ng-init="index()"     class="thumbnail">
     <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb">
       <img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}">
     </a>
      <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">{{phone.name}}</a>
     <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<div>
{{ filtered.length }}
</div>
```

To make more sense of data (Bonus Tip :) )

```
<div ng-show="query">
  <ng-pluralize count="filtered.length" when="{'0': ' No search result ', 'one': ' 1 search result ', 'other': ' {} search results '}"></ng-pluralize> for {{query}}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get total number of phones?
you can simply use length property in expression instead `{{ total }}`

```
{{ phones.length }}
```

Comment: not exactly,I want the number of times ng-repeat is repeated for a 'total'(value) dynamic.